# npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I got below error while trying to deploy my application through a Centos based dockerfile. Other npm modules installation were fine.
npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-repo/aws-amplify (over 30000ms)

Envr that I am running:
The npm install happens in a docker environment with Nodejs10.x
I have increased timeout by adding below commands in my dockerfile, but still get the same error as above

```
 && npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout 20000 \   (was 10000)
 && npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 300000    (was 60000)
```

Thanks in advance for any helps given !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original timeout seem reasonable.  Perhaps,  there is a bigger connectivity issue from your docker container to the artifactory server.  Can you replace your deploy script with 'sleep 60000',  then start it.  After you got container sleeping log into it using

```
docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash
```

and try to connect to your artifatory server.   Using a command like this

```
curl https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-repo/aws-amplify
```

If you don't get a response from curl, there is a greater connectivity issue that you have to address first.